# Documentation of =- (equals minus) in systemd unit files

Tags: systemd-unit

On my Archlinux system, the  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service` file contains these lines:

```
[Service]
Environment=  MDADM_MONITOR_ARGS=--scan
EnvironmentFile=-/run/sysconfig/mdadm
ExecStartPre=-/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/mdadm_env.sh
ExecStart=/sbin/mdadm --monitor $MDADM_MONITOR_ARGS
```

I suspect (confirmed by some googling) that the `=-` means that the service should not fail if the specified files are absent. However I failed to find that behaviour in the manpage of systemd unit files. Where is the official documentation for the `=-` assignment?

Comment: Note that it is just an ordinary `=` assignment, _not_ a second type of .INI file assignment syntax.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is documented in [`systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> `EnvironmentFile=`
>
> [...]
>
> The argument passed should be an absolute filename or wildcard expression, optionally prefixed with "`-`", which indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged.

And in [`systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> `ExecStart=`
>
> …
> For each of the specified commands, the first argument must be an absolute path to an executable. Optionally, this filename may be prefixed with a number of special characters:
>
> ## Table 1. Special executable prefixes
>
> …
>
> `ExecStartPre=`, `ExecStartPost=`
> …
> If any of those commands (not prefixed with `-`) fail, the rest are not executed and the unit is considered failed.

(To find the most complete documentation for a systemd directive, look it up in [`systemd.directives`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html).)

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, a line like

> After=-.mount

looks like another "equals minus"-Syntax but instead is just an `After=` directive listing the special system unit `-.mount`, which is the root mount point. 
Docs: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#-.mount