# Ignore file not found error in a environmentFile missing in a systemd

Tags: systemd, rhel, environment-variables, services

I have a service file that runs off Red Hat 7 and I'm reading values from a conf file with EnvironmentFile. I need to how "catch" (and ignore) the error that the file may not exist, and start anyway.

I already tried using `-` as prefix of the directive, but it did not start.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404199/documentation-of-equals-minus-in-systemd-unit-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [systemd.exec man page](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) says, with my emphasis:

> The **argument** passed should be an absolute filename or wildcard expression, optionally **prefixed with "-"**, which indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged.

So the syntax you need is:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/path/to/file
```

instead of:

```
-EnvironmentFile=/path/to/file
```